# How to pass single quotes to json string in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How do we convert this below json string into sinle quote in python. Below is my requirement scenario

test.py

```
import json

import sys

ss = {"fruite":"aapple", "code":"1xyz"}
```

Tried below commented different ways

```
#frmt = ("'{}'".format(ss))    ---->Everything is converted to single quotes, 
 
#ss2 = ("'"+ss+"'") not working

jsonld = json.loads(ss)
```

when i try this json loads its getting json decode error

If i give manually

```
ss = '{"fruite":"aapple", "code":"1xyz"}'
```

working json.loads , its didn't get any issue.

Expecting:

Here how do i pass single quotes to my above json string without changing inside double quotes.

Can you please suggest this

Comment: I don't understand the problem. `{"fruite":"aapple", "code":"1xyz"}` is a python literal that is converted to a dictionary and assigned to `ss` when the program is executed. Its not JSON at all, its already python, so `json.load` which converts strings to python won't work. If you wanted to create a json string you could `json.dumps(ss)` but I don't see any reason for `json.load` to be in the code. What is your goal? To make a python `dict`? You already did that.

Answer (score 2):

The json module provides functions to build a json string from a Python object:

```
ss = {"fruite":"aapple", "code":"1xyz"}
js = json.dumps(ss)
print(js)
```

Correctly prints:

```
{"fruite":"aapple", "code":"1xyz"}
```

But `js` is now a string and not a dictionary so you can load it:

```
jsonld = json.loads(js)
print(jsonld == ss)
```

prints

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks @Serge Ballesta, It works. I am able to load the js string without converting into single quotes.

Comment: @Nathon: never try to convert *by hand* where the conversion exists in a standard module. Their code has been extensively tested and is robust to corner cases, while yours may not.